# normalization of convolution product when using Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I'm trying to calculate the convolution of two probability density functions (PDFs) defined on the real axis:

a normal distribution (with `\[Sigma]` > 0 and `\[Mu]` a real number):

```
f[x_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_] := 
 1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma]) Exp[-(1/2) ((x - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^2]
```

and a Breit-Wigner distribution:

```
g[x_, m_, \[CapitalGamma]_] := 
  1 / ((x - m)^2 + 1/4 * \[CapitalGamma]^2) * \[CapitalGamma] / (2 * Pi)
```

with `\[CapitalGamma]` > 0 and `m` > 0.

I checked that for both of them the integral from minus infinity to infinity is one.

I'm interested in calculating the convolution of them which I do with Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms:

```
conv = Assuming[{\[CapitalGamma] > 0 && 
  m > 0 && \[Sigma] > 0 && \[Mu] \[Element] Reals},  
  InverseFourierTransform[
  FourierTransform[f[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma]], x, w] * 
  FourierTransform[g[x, m, \[CapitalGamma]], x, w],
 w, x]
]
```

This gives me a closed form solution:

```
(E^(-((2 m - 2 x - I \[CapitalGamma] + 2 \[Mu])^2/(
   8 \[Sigma]^2))) (1 - 
    I Erfi[(2 m - 2 x - I \[CapitalGamma] + 2 \[Mu])/(
      2 Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])]) + 
 E^(-((2 m - 2 x + I \[CapitalGamma] + 2 \[Mu])^2/(
   8 \[Sigma]^2))) (1 + 
    I Erfi[(2 m - 2 x + I \[CapitalGamma] + 2 \[Mu])/(
      2 Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])]))/(4 \[Pi] \[Sigma])
```

I expect the convolution product to [have unit area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration) again. I managed to manipulate the analytic expression for the indefinite integral of the convolution product but I find that after taking the limits I get `1/Sqrt[2*Pi]` ($\approx 0.398942$) rather than one. A numerical example with bounds chosen quite large:

```
N[
 NIntegrate[
  Re[conv /. { \[CapitalGamma] -> 2.4952, 
   m -> 91.1876, \[Mu] -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 2}] , {x, -1000, 1000}]
 ]
```

also gives a numerical value (0.398623) close to `1/Sqrt[2*Pi]`.

Is this expected or did I do a mistake ?

---

**Checks**:

I checked that when Fourier and inverse Fourier transforming the original PDFs `f` and `g` I get the original PDFs `f` and `g` without any additional factor.

Direct convolution: Using the `Convolve[]` function I need to do some variable substitution to get a closed form result:

```
convStd = 
 Assuming[{\[CapitalGamma] > 0 && 
 m > 0 && \[Sigma] > 0 && \[Mu] \[Element] Reals && 
 x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals},
                 Convolve[f[x, \[Mu], \[Sigma]] /.  x -> u + \[Mu],

 g[x, m, \[CapitalGamma]]  /. x -> u + \[Mu],
                                   u, y]
 ] /. y -> x
```

While I did not manage to get a closed form expression for the indefinite integral, a numerical example:

```
N[
 NIntegrate[
  Re[convStd /. { \[CapitalGamma] -> 2.4952, 
     m -> 91.1876, \[Mu] -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 2}] , {x, -1000, 1000}]
 ]
```

shows that the area of the convolution product is close to one (0.999199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely lies with the scaling in FourierParameters. Let's take a simpler example with f[t] = DiracDelta[t]:

```
InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[DiracDelta[t], t, w] *
                        FourierTransform[DiracDelta[t], t, w], w, t]

DiracDelta[t]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
```

This is the same awkward scaling as you are finding. This can be fixed using FourierParameters->{1,-1}

```
InverseFourierTransform[
   FourierTransform[DiracDelta[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] *
   FourierTransform[DiracDelta[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}], w, t, 
                       FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

 DiracDelta[t]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response ! With `{1, -1}` it gives the expected unit normalization.

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit in more detail, I realize that distributing the overall normalization factor between Fourier and inverse transform does not matter for single functions (as long as the product of the factors of both directions is correct) but when taking products in Fourier space one  effectively has the transform constant **twice** while one applies the inverse transform's constant only once when transforming back. This must be why when testing the normalization with one function only everything looked ok in my tests.